# Google analytics not recording conversion data in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2, google-analytics

We have recently updated to **Magento 2.3.2** and google analytics module stopped working. I can see the empty array **OrdersTrackingCode** in generated google analytics code on frontend.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the issue, that was GA and Google Tag manager event observer name were same:
**name="googleanalytics_order_success"**

After adding ga in end of name, it started working fine.
Replace below content in `vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/etc/frontend/events.xml` of Google Analytics